# Trouble returning in recursive call

Tags: python, recursion

I have successfully completed and passed a project for a course I am taking where I create all possible 4 letter password combinations for cracking a DES hash. When I find a match, it should return immediately but I know that my function is poorly designed. I understand basic recursion but I have always had trouble understanding it for any useful purposes. In this case I found that the only way I could make the method return is by checking a password variable initialized in the encapsulating function along with the nonlocal attribute.

I had this working without nonlocal before I came to my final solution, but it would continue for a while without returning anything even though it correctly printed out the password when found.

How can I correctly use recursion to return the correct password by propagating the value up correctly? Thank you for any help or tips that you can provide!

```
def brute_force_crack(hashed_pass):
    char_list = create_possible_chars()

    # Store all string combinations
    password = ""

    # Build the combos adding each letter to each prefix and then to combos.
    def build_combos(curr_str):

        nonlocal password

        # Check password to return early
        if password != "":
            return
        if len(curr_str) == 4:
            return

        for letter in char_list:
            # Add letter to curr_str to build up the combo
            curr_str += letter

            if is_password(curr_str, hashed_pass):
                password = curr_str
                break

            build_combos(curr_str)
            # Reset curr_str to be used again in this iteration without the added letter
            curr_str = curr_str[:-1]

    build_combos("")
    return password
```

Comment: "I had this working without nonlocal before I came to my final solution"
May we see the previous version please? The use of nonlocal was likely a step in the wrong direction.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The only difference is the original didn't initially check the password and inside the loop I attempted to return the curr_str instead or breaking out of the loop. Unfortunately I could only print from there because the return statement had nowhere to propagate to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should aim to let the recursive function *return* the correct password when found, instead of setting a non local variable.

Secondly, perform the password check at the start of the recursive function, at the same time you check for failure. This may seem overkill the first time (as an empty string will not match), but it is cleaner code.

Here is how it could look:

```
def brute_force_crack(hashed_pass):
    char_list = create_possible_chars()

    # Build the combos adding each letter to each prefix and then to combos.
    def build_combos(curr_str):
        # Check for success
        if is_password(curr_str, hashed_pass):
            # Return the match
            return curr_str
        # Check for failure
        if len(curr_str) >= 4:
            return

        for letter in char_list:
            # Add letter via argument to build up the combo
            password = build_combos(curr_str + letter)
            # If a result is returned, we can quit
            if password:
                return password

    # Return whatever is returned recursively
    return build_combos("")
```

Comment: This makes more sense to me. I can definitely see how the return value can be propagated up to the original call. I also see how unnecessary my string slicing was. Thank you for your help-it's greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure that when you find the right answer, you return it. Every path through your function should return something, either the correct password or a sentinel value (e.g. `None`) indicating failure. See if the below makes sense to you:

```
import string

def create_possible_chars():
    return string.ascii_lowercase

# Dummy implementation, check for the password reversed
def is_password(curr_str, hashed_pass):
    return ''.join(reversed(curr_str)) == hashed_pass

def brute_force_crack(hashed_pass):
    char_list = create_possible_chars()

    def build_combos(curr_str=""):
        # Base case: already at four characters, give up
        if len(curr_str) == 4:
            return None

        for letter in char_list:
            # Try adding this letter
            guess = curr_str + letter

            if is_password(guess, hashed_pass):
                # If this is the password, return it
                return guess
            else:
                # Recurse
                result = build_combos(guess)

                # If we found the password, return it
                if result is not None:
                    return result

        # We failed to find the psasword
        return None

    return build_combos()

print(brute_force_crack("beef"))  # feeb
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @smarx!